# Separate values from string in Lua

Tags: json, string, lua

How to separate all values from this string?

```json
{"coffre":[{"count":4,"name":"bread"},{"count":23,"name":"weed"}],"black_money":[{"amount":2410}]}
```

As a result, I would like to receive the following text.

```
bread - 4
weed - 23
black_money - 2410
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Adapt as needed.

```
s='{"coffre":[{"count":4,"name":"bread"},{"count":23,"name":"weed"}],"black_money":[{"amount":2410}]}'

for c,n in s:gmatch('"count":(.-),"name":"(.-)"') do
    print(n,c)
end

for n,c in s:gmatch('"([^"]+)":%[{"amount":(.-)}') do
    print(n,c)
end
```